# What's the difference between ESLint and the normal console errors?

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, eslint

I use the normal error logging in the console...
Following the call stack trace and all. Never had much of a problem.

A friend recommended ESLint. After looking at some screenshots, I don't see much of a difference between what ESLint does and normal error logging.

Could anyone please compare the two, perhaps giving pro's and con's.

Bonus Points: include some use-cases in which one would be better than the other.

Comment: ESLint can give you errors in an editor before you even try to test your code in a browser. [Take this editor extension for example](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

Answer (score 1):

A linting tool helps me avoid silly mistakes when writing JavaScript. Despite my many years of experience, I still type variable names incorrectly, make syntax errors and forget to handle my errors properly. A good linting tool, or a linter, will tell me about this before I waste my time—or worse, my client’s time. A good linting tool can also help make sure a project adheres to a coding standard.

There are many linters available for JavaScript like JSLint, JSHint, JSCS and ESLint, Let’s take a look at at pros and cons of alternatives:

**Pros**

- avoid silly mistakes when writing JavaScript
- avoid making syntax errors
- adheres to a coding standard
- Comes configured and ready to go (if you agree with the rules it
  enforces)
- Best ES6 support, and also the only tool to support JSX
- Resolve error before compiling with good IDE plugin for linting
  etc..

**Cons**

- You can’t add custom rules (not for all cases)
- Difficult to know which rule is causing which error
- Some configuration required
- Slow, but not a hindrance

**Examples:**

1. Strict type checking in conditions:

you will get lint error for no strict type checking in below code.

```
`a == b && foo == null`
```

with lint error you can resolve to this to avoid

```
`a === b && foo === null`
```

2. variable not defined

you will get lint error for no variable declared in below code.

> 'foo' is assigned a value but never used. and  'bar' is not defined.

```
var foo = bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

**ESLint:**

ESLint is a ***[linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))*** -a tool that analyzes your code and flags potential errors. This is very helpful to avoid common mistakes that are made while you're coding (using undefined variables, syntactic errors, etc).

*Pros:*

- Helps preventing syntactic mistakes
- Helps preventing common errors
- Helps you adhere to coding conventions
- ...

*Cons:*

- Need to setup
- It can get a bit annoying sometimes...

**Browser Console:**

On the other side, the ***console*** is a tool that you can find in all modern browsers. As opposed to a linter, in the console you'll find runtime errors -ie. errors occurred during the execution of your code.

---

**ESLint vs Console:**

You don't have to choose between one or the other. Both cover different needs and both can help you deliver better software.

If you're coding Front-End JavaScript, I'm sure you already use your browser console on a daily basis.

On top of that, you can choose to use a linter or not.